# 405 Error jQuery using IIS 6

Tags: jquery, iis, post

I am getting a 405 Error when I attempt to call my file through jQuery using IIS 6

```
map.load("areas.txt", {}, function(){
```

Im using IIS 6 on a Windows 2003 Machine. Just running from a basic HTML page, and I cant get it to work properly. Ive done some research but doesnt seem to be giving me anything I can do to fix it. My Page doesn't contain a form tag, but its still trying to POST.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Either the problem is that a `POST` is being dispatched, or the problem is that your server is returning 405 errors for `POST` requests. Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like that

```
$("#DivId").load("areas.txt", function(){

//your code

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and I found this:

> The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.